# What is the difference between "honesty" and "sincerity"?

Tags: adjectives

I feel like they can sometimes be interchanged:

> John gave a very **sincere** statement
>
> John gave a very **honest** statement

But sometimes they can not:

> I would like to offer my sincere thanks
>
> An honest man would not do such a thing

I feel like sincere has more of an emotional component to it?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: Sincerity implies self-awareness whereas honesty does not

Comment: I just got a call informing me that the caller had made several attempts to reach me , and that this was my last chance to lower the interest on my credit card. I hung up, because I suspected the caller was honest but insincere.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like sincerity is honesty coming from a more emotionally driven place. Some people are honest for the sake of being honest, whether by routine or just morals. But when you are sincere, then you are being honest in a very heartfelt way. Not sure if that adheres to the dictionary definition but that's just the general way I see it.

Comment: I agree with you Eddie, the degree of honesty in a statement can be determined by checking facts but the degree of sincerity cannot be independently verified, only experienced.